# Playa within a Grid field

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, grid

I've just installed Playa 4.5 to try and get around an edge case I'm having with searching and EE's native relationship fields. I basically need to have a single relationship dropdown in a grid field (again, EE native). The problem is there doesn't seem to be an option to add a Playa field into grid. Is this possible, or do I also have to buy Matrix? (It feels slightly unfair if I do!)

Thanks!

Comment: There was a little tension between Pixel and Tonic and Ellislabs about ExpressionEngine adding the grid fieldtype. It would be nice to know what kind of issues you are having with searching and using EE's relationships fields.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now (25 July 2014), you can not have playa in an ExpressionEngine grid field. So order to use playa, you will have to use matrix.

As for your edge case, maybe you could post another question and we could try and help you with the searching issue you are having.

Answer (score -3):

Can you tell us what version of EE you're using? If you're using a version that has native Relationships, you should use those instead of playa.

If you're using one without native Relationships, you should use Matrix instead of Grid.

Comment: Reading the question, you can see that Joe has a version that has relationships, but is having a problem with the search functionality.

Comment: He says he needs to have a single relationship dropdown, but he says there doesn't seem to be an option to add a play field into it. I think he means "to have a single playa relationship dropdown" and is not noticing relationships are native.

Comment: @JohnathanWaters is correct. I am using 2.7.3 and was using native relationships. Using Low Search no results were returned when the title of the related entry was searched for. Put a support request in to Low which can be seen [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_search_searching_on_related_entries_within_a_grid_field) (the basis for me switching to Playa). Have now purchased matrix as well as seemed like easiest solution. All is working now.

Comment: Do you mind me asking why you are using low search instead of native search? In my experience, native is always faster.